# 'The type or namespace name could not be found ' how to solve in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to setup play movement with a unity script from a you tube video Im watching.  currently I'm getting the error

> "The type of namespace name 'RigidBody2D' could not be found"

I have a RigidBody2D Attached to my sprite an I'm pretty lost on what to do next. 
here is my cod any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    [RequireComponent(typeof(RigidBody2D))]
    // this makes sure if a rigid body doesnt exist in the player it will add one

    public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public RigidBody2D playerRigidBody;
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;


    public void Awake()
    {
      playerRigidBody = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
      if(playerRigidBody != null)
      {
          ApplyInput();
      }
      else
      {
        Debug.LogWarning("rigid body not attached to player" +GameObject.name);
      }
    }


    //Chek to see if any buttions are pushed down and if so perform any relivent action

      public void ApplyInput()
    {
    float HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float VerticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    float HorizontalForce = HorizontalInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;


      Vector2 force = new Vector2(HorizontalForce,0);
     playerRigidBody.AddForce(force);


    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this class name:

```
RigidBody2D
```

with this:

```
Rigidbody2D
```

Here is the reference for the [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) class.

Comment: [Should we answer or comment on a typo question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question)